# Save the data from an array that changes every second

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, audio

Im doing an app that will calculate the HBR in Unity.

So when the user click on the microphone button, it starts recording and it gets the Spectrum Data of the by the command GetSpectrumData in an Array. What I want to do is to get the spectrum each second (15 seconds) stock in the array and save it in another one.

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class Data : MonoBehaviour
{

AudioSource _audio;
public float[] _samples1, arreglo = new float[512];
void Start()
{
    _audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    _audio.clip = Microphone.Start("Built-in Microphone", true, 15, 44100);

}

void Update()
{

    GetSpectrum();

    for (int i = 0; i > 15; i++)
    {
        arreglo.add(_samples1[i]);

    }


}

void GetSpectrum()
{
    _audio.GetSpectrumData(_samples1, 0, FFTWindow.Blackman);


}
}
```

The problem is when I run it i does not recognize the command add.

I will appreciate if somebody could help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Arrays don't have an `add` method. `List<T>` do have an `Add` method. Is that what you need?

Comment: IList<T> and ICollection<T> have the Add method. And it's 'Add' not 'add'.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i > 15; i++)` is wrong and probably a typo? If something it should probably be `for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)`? Currently it will skip the loop immediately since the condition `i > 15` is never met since you do `i=0` as start ...

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class Data : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource _audio;
    public float[] _samples1 = new float[512];
    public List<float> arreglo = new List<float>();

    void Start()
    {
        _audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        _audio.clip = Microphone.Start("Built-in Microphone", true, 15, 44100);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        GetSpectrum();

        // optional if you want to clear old data
        arreglo.Clear();

        // replace 15 with '_samples1.Length' for adding all values
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            arreglo.Add(_samples1[i]);
        }
    }

    void GetSpectrum()
    {
        _audio.GetSpectrumData(_samples1, 0, FFTWindow.Blackman);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of what you changed and how that solves the problem. An answer is ment to not let any doubts or questions open.

Comment: You also copied the wrong `for(int i = 0; i > 15; i++)` that makes no sense

Comment: I used **List<>** instead of array. And I thought that OP needs only 15 elements, so I did not changed that part.

Comment: but it doesn't copy 15 elements ... it copies none because the condition `i > 15` is never met